# Error occured: CredentialsSignin when trying to log in using Phantom provider

Tags: authentication, next.js13, solana, next-auth

I'm developing an application in Next.js 14 for one project. You need to authenticate using the Phantom wallet for the Solana blockchain. On localhost:3000 everything works correctly and on preview deploy in vercel, everything works correctly, but on the main domain the following error occurs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM6EW.png)

I thought use [Moralis](https://moralis.io/), but it have big bundle.

next auth

```
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'web3',
      credentials: {
        signature: {
          label: 'Signature',
          type: 'text'
        },
        message: {
          label: 'Message',
          type: 'text'
        }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!credentials?.message) {
          return null
        }
        const { publicKey, host } = JSON.parse(credentials?.message)

        const nextAuthUrl = new URL(getURL())

        if (host !== nextAuthUrl.host) {
          return null
        }
        const crsf = await getCsrfToken({ req: { ...req, body: null } })

        if (!crsf) {
          return null
        }
        const nonceUnit8 = Signature.create(crsf)

        const isValidate = await Signature.validate(
          {
            signature: credentials?.signature,
            publicKey
          },
          nonceUnit8
        ).then((res) => res.valueOf)

        if (!isValidate) {
          throw new Error('Could not validate the signed message')
        }

        return { id: publicKey }
      }
    })
  ],

  session: { strategy: 'jwt' },

  debug: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV === 'development',

  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.name = token.sub
        session.user.image = `https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=${token.sub}`
      }
      return session
    }
  }
}
```

Fn for connect wallet

```
import base58 from 'bs58'
import { getCsrfToken, signIn } from 'next-auth/react'

import { getProvider } from '../hooks/getProvider'
import { Signature } from './Signature'

export const onConnect = async () => {
  try {
    const provider = getProvider()

    if (!provider) {
      window.open('https://phantom.app/', '_blank')
    }

    const resp = await provider.connect()
    console.log('Connect', resp.publicKey.toString())
    const csrf = await getCsrfToken()
    if (resp && csrf) {
      const noneUnit8 = Signature.create(csrf)
      const { signature } = await provider.signMessage(noneUnit8)
      const serializedSignature = base58.encode(signature)
      const message = {
        host: window.location.host,
        publicKey: resp.publicKey.toString(),
        nonce: csrf
      }
      const response = await signIn('credentials', {
        message: JSON.stringify(message),
        signature: serializedSignature,
        redirect: false
      })
      console.log(response)
      if (response?.error) {
        console.log('Error occured:', response.error)
        return
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Could not connect to wallet')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

This getURL()

```
export const getURL = () => {
  if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV === 'development')
    return 'http://localhost:3000'
  else return `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL}`
}
```

Comment: Try hardcoding your `NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL` value when deployed. Also your [`NEXTAUTH_URL`](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#environment-variables) environment variable in your Vercel configuration needs to be set to your live domain.